Bypassing DHCP DNS with systemd-resolved
The issue
Changing the DNS option in resolv.conf from the VM's gateway to 8.8.8.8 will result in no DNS resolution.
resolvectl query google.com succeeds if I set DNS to my gateway.
The set-up

/etc/resolv.conf is linked to stub-resolv.conf

systemd-networkd is configured as follows:
[Match]
Name=enp0s3

[Network]
Address=192.168.0.222/24
Gateway=192.168.0.1
DNS=8.8.8.8


/etc/systemd/resolv.conf has not been modified



Additional troubleshooting

I tried linking /etc/resolv.conf to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf instead and only listing 8.8.8.8 as nameserver there. But systemd-resolved overwrites /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf


Changing the /etc/resolv.conf link to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf and listing the DNS in /etc/systemd/network/foo.network and in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf made it so that the global and NIC settings listed by resolvectl point to 8.8.8.8 and succesfully resolve.
